# Crystal Report Print Dynamic PageSize

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i want crystal report print continuously based on report like if report finishes stop the printing without blank page with dotmatrix printer(e.g Departmental store Bill).i am mention design in report A4 size but,i want to print report without blank page.

currently my output is like below image:

[image]

I want output like below image:

[image]

I am using C#.net,View and Print using Crystal Report Viewer.I am not experience Crystal Report can any one help me how can do this?

Thanks For Reading My Post.

Comment: Have you found the answer? If yes, please share. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you avoid white-space in each section by using the Fit Section command which can be accessed from the context menu. Also make sure that the Extent Section to the bottom of the page is also unchecked for both report and page footers.